# What do the % and %% operators do when setting up SBT dependencies?

Tags: scala, lift, sbt

In Lift Web Framework, dependencies for Simple Build Tool (SBT) are specified in LiftProject.scala. That file includes this code:

```
  override def libraryDependencies = Set(
    "net.liftweb"             %% "lift-webkit"   % liftVersion % "compile->default",
    "net.liftweb"             %% "lift-mapper"   % liftVersion % "compile->default",
    "org.mortbay.jetty"       % "jetty"          % "6.1.22"    % "test->default",
    "junit"                   % "junit"          % "4.5"       % "test->default",
    "org.scala-tools.testing" %% "specs"         % "1.6.6"     % "test->default",
    "org.scala-lang"          % "scala-compiler" % "2.8.1"     % "test->default",
    "org.apache.tomcat"       % "tomcat-juli"    % "7.0.0"     % "test->default",
    "com.h2database"          % "h2"             % "1.2.138"
  ) ++ super.libraryDependencies
```

What do the % and %% operators do here? If I paste this code into the scala interpreter, it errors out, and neither % nor %% is defined for String or RichString. What's going on here?

Comment: I applied a bit of formatting to make it more table-like. I hope you don't mind, but, if you do, feel free to revert my edit.

Answer (score 15):

The difference between these functions is that `%%` considers Scala version when SBT resolve dependency, so for example `net/liftweb/lift-webkit_2.8.1/2.3/lift-webkit_2.8.1-2.3.jar` will be downloaded from repo.

Regarding compile error - these methods should be called when some implicit methods defined in SBT class hierarchy that make actual conversion are in scope.

Best regards,
Vladimir

Answer (score 8):

They control grabbing builds for a specific version of Scala.

% grabs the dependency exactly as you described it.

%% tacks the Scala version into the resource name to fetch a version for the local Scala build. Extra useful.if you crossbuild for several releases of Scala.

Answer (score 4):

Since 2011, the doc got a bit more complete: "[Library dependencies](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Dependencies.html) ".

The article "[Sbt heiroglyphs and multi-projects explained](https://medium.com/from-the-couch/sbt-heiroglyphs-and-multi-projects-explained-ee0aef3efdce#.fme03erbj)" from [Divan Visagie](https://twitter.com/DivanVisagie) also details those sbt operators:

> `%` and `%%` get a little tricky: they define the ids and versions of each library in the sequence , but it’s safe to say that:

```
"org.scala-tools" % "scala-stm_2.11.1" % "0.3"
```

> Is the equivalent of

```
"org.scala-tools" %% "scala-stm" % "0.3"
```

> So effectively the extra `%%` means it figures out what Scala version you are on.

The doc adds:

> The idea is that many dependencies are compiled for multiple Scala versions, and you’d like to get the one that matches your project to ensure binary compatibility.
>
> The complexity in practice is that often a dependency will work with a slightly different Scala version; but `%%` is not smart about that.
> So if the dependency is available for 2.10.1 but you’re using `scalaVersion := "2.10.4"`, you won’t be able to use `%%` even though the 2.10.1 dependency likely works.
> If `%%` stops working, just go see which versions the dependency is really built for, and hardcode the one you think will work (assuming there is one).